# Why heroku kills my process with status 143?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've small app([git](https://github.com/IslamAlahovich/BAD_Repost_vk_BOT)) on node on Heroku that works with api for vk.com(social network), but Heroku kills it with SIGTERM after 30 min. I use setInterval which sends request to vk.com server and processes the response once every 20 min:

```
var timerID = setInterval( function reposting() {
```

`vk.executes("wall.get", [
     {owner_id: -97758272, count: 1, extended: true},
     {owner_id: -109933725, offset: 1, count:1, extended: true}
  ])
  .then((wall_list) => {
     wall_list.forEach(function(wall, index) {
        repost_and_join(wall, index);
     });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log("WALL_GET_ERROR: "+error);
  });`

}, 600000);

How to fix this problem, or maybe you know another free hosting where can deploy an app like this? ERRORLOG: [image: errorlog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add something like this in your code:

```
var reqTimer = setTimeout(function wakeUp() {
   request("https://nameless-gorge-19527.herokuapp.com", function() {
      console.log("WAKE UP DYNO");
   });
   return reqTimer = setTimeout(wakeUp, 1200000);
}, 1200000);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Free dynos are unique because they go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity.

From [Heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours)

Are you using free dynos by any chance?

If you're looking for a free service, maybe give aws lambda a try? They give you 1M free call per month i think, IIRC

Comment: @laser_sex_machine Or you can send ping(request) to your server every 30 minutes to wake up heroku dyno.